If I "may hold the land on trust so as to house an art gallery", then how can ownership disappear?
This footnote 12 is just knocking me for six !

12 Although the example in the text involves fragmented ownership, trusts are not always configured in this way. Sometimes, indeed, *while the trustee continues to have no rights, nobody else does either. For example, I may hold the land on trust so as to house an art gallery. Then, ownership simply disappears. [emphasis mine] But this raises the same kind of difficulty as fragmentation, namely the prima facie destruction of the land’s marketability; to which the law has responded in the same way, by the device of overreaching, described below.†

If  "I may hold the land on trust so as to house an art gallery", then I am the Trustee. According to  Equity Trust (Jersey) Ltd v Halabi (Jersey) [2022] UKPC 36

[para. 107] the trust property remains in the legal ownership or possession of the trustee.


[para. 70] the trustee remains the legal owner of those assets.

Thus there exists ownership! Legal ownership of the land and art gallery is mine! How on earth can "ownership simply disappears" ?
† Chapter 10, An Introduction to Land Law (2015 4th ed) by Prof. Simon Gardner (faculty of law, Oxford University).

Have you read through the "described below" section? Perhaps it clarifies.
